# What is the difference of firestore from firebase-functions and firebase-admin?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm using cloud functions to handle sensitive tasks of my app, I've seen documentation approaching it with using firestore that either lives on

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const { firestore } = functions
```

or

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()
const { firestore } = admin
```

My instinct says that if I use admin one I can bypass all security rules i.e read from and receive updates from any place in my firestoe, same with writes. So it seems that I can use firestore from admin everywhere, its identical to one from `firebase-functions` just has admin privileges?

Is this correct? If not what is the difference?

Can my project just use `firebase-admin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firestore-functions module is only for use with code deployed to Cloud Functions.  It doesn't do anything useful outside of that environment.

The firebase-admin SDK is for accessing your Firebase products on a backend server you control, which could be Cloud Functions, or even your desktop.  It will typically have full access to everything, as determined by the service account you used to initialize it.

Comment: I saw admin sdk used in cloud function tutorials you guys have, am I correct in understanding that I should use `firebase-functions` tooling for hooks / https listeners, but inside those functions I should be using admin sdk to get further data / write to firestore in order to bypass security rules?

Comment: Yes, you can see lots of examples of that.  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/generate-thumbnail